# Inspect vs AST argument specification compatbility

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a string that contains python code - more specifically a python function definition (using traditional function definition, not lambdas). For example:

```py
code = "def f(p,t,h, *, foo: str = 'foo'): return True"
```

I need to get the signature of the defined function as I need to assert that some properties are being met. As far as I know there are two approaches I could take: One involving `AST` module, and one involving `inspect` module.

#### Using AST module

```
import ast
root = ast.parse(code)
print(root.body[0].args.__dict__
```

This will print:

```
{'posonlyargs': [],
 'args': [<ast.arg at 0x7f87e06cd4c0>,
  <ast.arg at 0x7f87e06cd7c0>,
  <ast.arg at 0x7f8808074100>],
 'vararg': None,
 'kwonlyargs': [<ast.arg at 0x7f87e023d4c0>],
 'kw_defaults': [<ast.Constant at 0x7f87e023d6a0>],
 'kwarg': None,
 'defaults': []}
```

#### Using inspect

First execute the code to obtain a function object and then inspect its signature (I know `exec` is dangerous and I should not use it, don't worry).

```
import inspect
results = {}
exec(code, {}, results)
f = results['f']
print(inspect.getfullargspec(f))
```

This will print:

```py
FullArgSpec(args=['p', 't', 'h'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=None, kwonlyargs=['foo'], kwonlydefaults={'foo': 'foo'}, annotations={'foo': <class 'str'>})
```

I notice that some things are the same, for example the 'args' attribute of both things represent the same thing (or at least that's what I would expect) but for other things it's not so clear, for example, using `inspect` we get an attribute named `varkw` that is not present in the `AST.arguments` instance (although I think it can be `kwarg` attribute maybe?).

The question is: Is there a mapping between the two classes? Is all the info present in one retained in the other? If so, which attributes correspond to which?

Comment: I think `varkw` and `kwarg` are meant to represent the same information (the parameter `**kwarg` in a function header)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two approaches work with very different inputs, one should be seen as structured instructions, the other the reflection of the *result* of the instructions having been executed.

- The AST approach looks, presumably, at the very limited context of just the function definition. This can only tell you things about the static interpretation of that text. E.g. any keyword argument defaults or dynamic annotations are *not* going to be accurate without more context. Moreover, the default values and annotations are *expressions* that are used to executed by Python when the function is created, and could even be simplified during compilation.
- The `inspect` approach works on the current 'live' representation of the function object as loaded by the interpreter. Function objects are not static entities, various aspects of the object are actually mutable, so the signature generated could change depending on what other code has run and if that has acted on the function or on objects the function references.

To give an example, consider:

```py
from random import randint, choice

annotation = choice((str, int))

def foo(bar, baz = randint(0, 42), arg: annotation = None):
    pass

foo.__defaults__ = choice((foo.__defaults__, foo.__defaults__[::-1]))
```

Can you tell me what the default values for `baz` and `arg` will be from the source code alone? Or what type the `arg` argument is annotated with?

You can't, because the AST reflects *text as processed using Python's grammar rules*. The `inspect.getfullargspec()` named tuple reflects *Python objects as created by the Python interpreter, after executing bytecode generated from the AST*.

Put differently: the `inspect.getfullargspec()` result looks at function objects several stages further along the path from writing code to calling the function. If an analogy helps here: imagine being given detailed instructions on how to walk from a train station in a big city to a major museum, in a busy (pre-Covid-19) city. The detailed instructions can't account for any street vendors, road works, or inviting café's along the way, so your mobile phone GPS may not entirely agree with what path you actually took once you reach the museum. The detailed instructions are the AST, the `inspect.getfullargspec()` return value the actual path travelled.

That said, *disregarding dynamic content*, the inspect signature object should give you the same information as what you can get from the AST. The AST shows you what primitive objects and variables the Python interpreter will use to create the function object, and the `inspect.getfullargspec()` result only looks at the same pieces of information, but after the function was created.

You only printed the `ast.arguments` object `__dict__`, you want to use [`ast.dump()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.dump) to see a bit more. You have a *tree* of objects reflecting the source, so you need to look at the full depth to see what else is contained.

I've included all AST attributes in my dump, so you can see the annotations too:

```py
>>> import ast
>>> code = "def f(p,t,h, *, foo: str = 'foo'): return True"
>>> module = ast.parse(code)
>>> print(ast.dump(module.body[0].args, indent=4))
arguments(
    posonlyargs=[],
    args=[
        arg(arg='p'),
        arg(arg='t'),
        arg(arg='h')],
    kwonlyargs=[
        arg(
            arg='foo',
            annotation=Name(id='str', ctx=Load()))],
    kw_defaults=[
        Constant(value='foo')],
    defaults=[])
```

(the `indent` option to `ast.dump()` is new in Python 3.9).

You can see that all the same information is contained; the annotations are part of the [`ast.arg()` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.arg) contained; you'd have to *walk* the tree to collect those into a dictionary:

```py
>>> annotations = {}
>>> for node in ast.walk(module.body[0].args):
...     if isinstance(node, ast.arg) and node.annotation:
...         ann = node.annotation  # could be any valid Python expression!
...         annotations[node.arg] = ann.id if isinstance(ann, ast.Name) else str(ann)
...
>>> annotations
{'foo': 'str'}
```

To further illustrate, this is the AST tree for the contrived dynamic function definition using random values example I gave:

```
>>> print(ast.dump(module.body[2].args, indent=4))
arguments(
    posonlyargs=[],
    args=[
        arg(arg='bar'),
        arg(arg='baz'),
        arg(
            arg='arg',
            annotation=Name(id='annotation', ctx=Load()))],
    kwonlyargs=[],
    kw_defaults=[],
    defaults=[
        Call(
            func=Name(id='randint', ctx=Load()),
            args=[
                Constant(value=0),
                Constant(value=42)],
            keywords=[]),
        Constant(value=None)])
```

and the `inspect.getfullargspec()` result (well, *one* of the possible results):

```
>>> inspect.getfullargspec(foo)
FullArgSpec(args=['bar', 'baz', 'arg'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=(None, 16), kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={'arg': <class 'int'>})
```

There are obvious differences:

- The `arg` annotation is the name `annotation` in the AST, because the expression that references the `annotation` variable has not been executed. In the `getfullargspec()` the outcome of `random.choice()` picked the `int` class, but it could also have been `<class 'str'>`.
- The first keyword argument default is a *call* expression in the AST; the Python source code for `randint(0, 42)` is reflected, not the result of calling that function. The inspect result shows that in my case, `16` was picked.

Comment: It took me a while to fully process this info, and here I am, almost two year later, thanking you for this insightful post.